# Get Subscription from Already Connected Device Using RxAndroidBle

Tags: android, bluetooth, rx-java, rxandroidble

Is there a way to get a `Subscription` from an already connected device using RxAndroidBle? I can't seem to find a way aside from disconnecting and connecting again.

Comment: if the user connects his device outside of the app (BT os menu for example), the connection isn't available

Answer (score 1):

You are probably not interested in getting the `Subscription` from an already connected device but rather to get an instance of the emitted `RxBleConnection`.

It is more of an `RxJava` question then:
You can get this kind of behaviour (an `Observable<RxBleConnection>` that will emit `RxBleConnection` to any next subscriber if it had already emitted) for instance by using [`RxReplayingShare`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxReplayingShare/tree/replaying-share-parent-1.0.1). It would look like:

```
Observable<RxBleConnection> connectionObservable = rxBleDevice.establishConnection(false)
    .compose(ReplayingShare.instance());
```

Then, every subscriber to the `connectionObservable` will get the same `RxBleConnection` as long as it will be valid.

Be careful though because sometimes BLE communication is implemented as stateful (i.e. a request-response model) and this kind of sharing may introduce some hard to spot issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to maintain the `rxbleconnection` subscription and instance yourself. The library is stateless.